# is there way to simply convert JSON Array values to string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have json array data for people name like this.

```
'user': [{'name':'tom'},
         {'name':'jerry'}]
```

I want to convert user array to string value like this

```
"tom, jerry"
```

please, let me know how can I convert.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```js
var user =  [{'name':'tom'},
         {'name':'jerry'}]

console.log(user.map(function(item){return item.name;}).join(", "));
```

Comment: `.join(", ")` would respect the exact syntax OP asked for.